# No puedo mostrar los datos de una variable en la vista con Angular y Ionic 6

Tags: angular, ionic

Estoy accediendo a los datos de una variable desde el html, variable a la cual le asigno datos mediante una función asíncrona.

```
obtenerViaje(id){
  this.firebase.obtenerViaje(id).then((data)=>{
    data.subscribe(doc=>{
      this.viaje = JSON.stringify(doc.data());
      console.log(this.viaje);
    })
  })
}
```

Estoy obteniendo los datos para asignarle a la variable desde un servicio que obtiene los datos desde la base de datos.

```
async obtenerViaje(id){
  try{
    return await this.firestore.collection('Viajes').doc(id).get();
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Y al intentar mostrar por pantalla lo obtenido me muestra el mismo error.

```
<ion-card-content>
  <h1><b>Viaje</b></h1>
 <p>Capacidad: {{viaje.capacidad | async}}</p>
  <p>Matricula vehiculo: {{viaje.matricula | async}}</p>
  <p>Costo viaje: {{viaje.costo | async}}</p>
  <p>Destino: {{viaje.destino | async}}</p>
  <p>Hora de salida: {{viaje.salida | async}}</p> 
</ion-card-content>
```

No entiendo mucho cómo utilizar de manera correcta las promesas y los observers. Intenté de todo pero no puedo lograr mostrar por pantalla lo que necesito. Por consola se muestra lo obtenido correctamente pero la idea es mostrarlo en la vista.

Comment: No uses `JSON.stringify`, asignalo directamente: `this.viaje = doc.data()`

Comment: No es ese el problema, porque por consola se muestra de ambas maneras el tema es que cuando lo quiero mostrar por el html me lanza un error de undefined

Comment: Remueve el `async` del html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente el error del undefined sea porque la vista se carga antes de obtener los datos de la API (Firebase en este caso), y la vista intenta renderizar el objeto, el cual entiendo que la variable viaje no la inicializas antes de asignarle la respuesta de la API. Puedes probar a inicializarla vacía .

Comment: Probe inicializando la variable y como tu dijiste esa era la solución, muchas gracias. Quisiera entender por completo el funcionamiento de promesas y observers, algún consejo?

Comment: @NicolasQuijada este artículo es bastante interesante: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/angular-promises-versus-observables.aspx